# Can I create a tag automatically after PR approved in target branch in azure devops?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'd like to add a tag after the PR request finished in azure devops.
Should I use a web hook or other easy way to get it?

Comment: Here I got two ideas.1 use service web hook and post a HTTP request to execute the tag,but I thought it is a little complicated  2 If I can distinguish the PR policy trigger in the build pipeline, I can add a script to the pipeline to perform the tagging operation，but currently I have no idea about how to indentify?

Comment: Maybe all you need is a build.reason variable. In my opinion, if you set branch policy in master branch, then any changes in master have to be merged via PR. So `build.reason =PullRequest` represents the pipeline triggered by creating PR, `build.reason =Manual` represents the pipeline triggered by manual run, and `IndividualCI` will represent the statue of the completion of a PR. So `IndividualCI` is what you need ?

Comment: Yes,I agreed with you.It make sense as I will add a task to do the git tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I can distinguish the PR policy trigger in the build pipeline, I
>   can add a script to the pipeline to perform the tagging operation，but
>   currently I have no idea about how to indentify?

It seems the actual question of your issue is about how to identify if the pipeline runs from PR. For this, Azure Devops Service provide [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables):

We can use `Build.Reason` in condition to determine the event that causes the build to run.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using `YAML` pipelines you could add a tag with the following step as LAST step:

```
- powershell: |
    Write-Host "Tagging Build: $env:BuildNumber"

    git tag $env:BuildNumber
    git push origin $env:BuildNumber
  env:
    BuildNumber: $(Build.BuildNumber)
  condition: succeeded()
```

see `condition: succeeded()` will only execute this step if the previous one was successful.

Comment: Do you mean I should add a task in my build pipeline?

Comment: yes. Add it at last step in your build pipeline. if everything you want is succesful apply the tag.

Comment: And I just want to identify the Tag after the PR is completed, I set the PR from the branch policy, how do I distinguish the build comes from PR?

Comment: maybe it would help if you clarify the question

Comment: I have a build pipeline and I added build validation in my branch.I want to verify which build comes from PR so that I can only add tags after PR completed,not every build pipeline.